# How to reload all Firefox tabs in one specific group(Tab Candy)

Tags: firefox

I've started using Tab Candy recently, which has been in Firefox since version 4 apparently. One thing I would like to be able to do is reload all tabs in one such group I created, but not the others.

I can't find an option for this and the add-on site isn't returning any results either.

Does anyone know a setting or add-on that can do this?

Comment: Was the feature available with Tab Candy from the start?

Comment: Could you give a reference for Tab Candy? And: In what way does Tab Candy differ from the build-in Tab-Group feature of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the default tab restoring option that Firefox implements. Press Alt to show the menu and then History -> Recently closed tabs -> Select the tabs you want to restore.

This will reopen the tabs in the original tab group in which they were.